# Ошибка при установке Kubuntu 13.10 на ноутбук Acer Aspire 5750G

Tags: установка, kubuntu, ноутбук

Подскажите пожалуйста, как решить следующую проблему. Впервые решил установить Linux. Выбрал дистрибутив Kubuntu 13.10 x64 для установки на ноутбук Acer Aspire 5750G. Скачал с официального сайта ( kubuntu.org ), записал на флешку программой Linux Live USB. Перезагружаю компьютер и гружусь с флешки, чтобы начать установку. Некоторое время установка идет, после чего останавливается на строке

```
nouveau [    VBIOS] checking PRAMIN for image...
```

и более никак не реагирует.Поиск в интернете показал, что, возможно, проблема в видеокартах, так как их две - nVidia и intel. Но решения найдено не было.

Answer (score 1):

Решение было найдено: нужно при загрузке флешки до начала установки включить опцию nomodest [ F6 - nomodest ]

Answer (score 0):

рекомендую установить 12.04.3LTS x86 alternate версию. Вам будет намного проще знакомиться с системой, оперативку тянет также хорошо как и х64. x64 необходима в очень редких случаях, а геморроя хапните мало не покажется.

При установке alternate версии рекомендую установку (ОЕМ) версии, она у меня чаще других встаёт нормально, это можно выбрать сразу после выбора языка (внизу)

Ещё раз повторюсь. Не нужно гнаться за версиями, стабильность дороже.

Comment: Спасибо за совет, но, к сожалению, он не является ответом на вопрос.

Answer (score 0):

Для новичков лучше linux mint там большинство програм уже предустановлено и интерфейс по понятней. Лучше не используй ветку 13.10 она не стабильна лучше 12.04 в крайнем случае 13.04. считай всё что с xx.10 -это тестовые не стабильные релизы.

Comment: 64x смотря какое железо если старое, то 32x, а вообще есть архитектура pae которая держит и 32 и 64